# Get value of navigation property on entity that has not been saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

Lets say I have a Customers and Orders table:

```
_Customers_    _Orders_
IdCustomer     OrderNumber
Name           IdCustomer
Etc            Etc
```

When I use the entity framework its very nice how it creates navigation properties meaning I can do:

```
var context = new MyEntities(); 
var c = context.Orders.First().Customer;
```

That woks great because the first order exist on the database. How can I take advantage of navigational properties in order to avoid creating a join for records that do not exist on the database. **In other words**:

```
var myNewOrder = new Order(){ IdCustomer =2, OrderNumber=3123, etc...}
var context = new MyEntities(); 
var c = context.Orders.Attach(context).Customer;
```

in this case c is null because that order does not exist on the database. How can I take advantage of navigational properties without having to save the order? I want to do some validation prior on saving.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can attach the new object to the context and then use Context.Orders.Local, with the Local property. Local represents a represents a local view of all Added, Unchanged, and Modified entities.

```
var myNewOrder = new Order(){ IdCustomer =2, OrderNumber=3123, etc...}
var context = new MyEntities(); 
var c = context.Orders.Attach(myNewOrder);

var attatchedOrder = context.Orders.Local.SingleOrFirst(o => o.IdCustomer);
```

More about Local on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.113%29.aspx